# Where do I get my exit stamp on my passport?

Tags: schengen

I have flight from Gdansk, Poland to Istanbul. However, first I will go to Warsaw and then Istanbul with the same airline (LOT Polish). Does anybody know whether I will get my exit stamp in Gdansk or in Warsaw (the airline is same)?

The reason I ask is I want to get a tax declaration for something bought here to refund. It needs a Schengen exit stamp. Where should I get it?

Comment: You need to familiarize yourself with the process & the documentation requirements. Typically you need to bring invoices that have the non EU address as the delivery address.  You should also research how to find the customs office for this sort of thing, they tend to be out the way in most airports.

Comment: I have rolled back to the edited version, as it is an improvement and it is normal on this site to improve posts.

Answer (score 15):

Immigration and customs are two different things in Europe. The exit stamp you will get in your passport has nothing in common with the export stamp you need for your invoices. For the purpose of getting your VAT back what needs to be certified is that the goods in question have left the EU, not necessarily you...

You will pass through exit passport control in Warsaw, as that is where you leave the Schengen area.

To get you invoices stamped you will need to go to a customs office. If the merchandise is in your checked luggage you will need to do this in Gdansk, as they often want to see it. Even for stuff in your hand luggage doing it in Gdansk is probably better as the customs offices are usually land side.

Comment: Thanks are you sure they do not need the exit stamp before refund? we do not have luggage actually. If we can do it in Gdansk we should go to custom and the custom is where exactly generally in airport?

Comment: You are confusing the exit stamp, which you get in your passport, with the export stamp, which customs will apply to your invoice. So you have to look for the customs office at the airport. Where that is, depends on the airport. But it usually is land side before security.

Answer (score 5):

Specifically for Warsaw (Chopin airport) here's the full information on getting the VAT refund:
https://www.lotnisko-chopina.pl/en/tax-refund.html

The location is:

> Customs office is located in landside between B and C check-in zones and in passenger zone after passport control.

which I understand are effectively two options:

- for travelers actually leaving from Warsaw - that's before security, next to check-in stands
- or for people transferring (like you) in a not so specified "passenger zone". I'd look for big signs saying "customs" or its Polish counterpart "cło".

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I get the paperwork in Gdansk and give it to my friend to turn it back to the media market shopping center to get the refund? Since media market told me you can bring  your paper here to get refund . Actually I will buy it to my wife and she will go to non-eu country and turn back after 2 months. I am not sure whether I could get it and turn back to the media market to get refund or the money will absolutely be given after I get the exit stamp in my pass

Comment: @AhmadTurani you seem to have missed a few things about VAT refunds. VAT refunds are for final exports. If you bring the goods back into the EU after that it will be like you bought the goods outside the EU and imported them, so unless the value is below the duty free allowance you have to pay VAT, taxes and duties, which will be more than the refund you got.

Comment: @jarcon I did not confuse. Media market itself told me to do that. They said go to airport bring custom paperwork and we will pay back!

Comment: Look. Mediamarket told me that you buy a cell phone (for instance) with your passport name. Then you will go to airport with your ticket. Then you will shown it to custom with your ticket. After that they give you a paper with barcode and so on. Then you can go to passport check and after the security and pass exit you can get your money back. Or you can bring your paper to us to refund the tax part to you!